# Issues while error checking two variables with hasNext method

Tags: java

I am taking a Java class and I am stuck on an assignment using the hasNext command to error check two user entered variables to make sure they are numerical. This is what I have so far.

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    String choice = "y";
    double firstside;
    double secondside;

    //obtain user input
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {


    System.out.println("Enter First Side: ");
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        firstside = sc.nextDouble();

    } else {
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value and try again.");
        continue;
    }

    while (true){
    System.out.println("Enter Second Side: ");
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        secondside = sc.nextDouble();
        break;
    } else {
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a numeric value and try again.");
    }
    }

    //calculate results
    double hypotenusesquared = Math.pow(firstside, 2) + Math.pow(secondside, 2);
    double hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(hypotenusesquared);

    //display results
    String output = "Hypotenuse = " + hypotenuse;
    System.out.println(output);
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Y/N?");
    choice = sc.next();
}
```

} 
}

The output I am receiving when there is an error is:

> Please enter a numeric value and try again. Enter First Side: Please enter a numeric value and try again. Enter First Side:

I intend to only receive:

> Please enter a numeric value and try again. Enter First Side:

Comment: It's because you have one big loop that asks for both "first side" and "second side".  If you go back to the beginning of the loop, it will ask for "first side" again, because that's what's at the beginning of the loop.  Your program has nothing that enables it to go back to the "second side" question.  To fix that, put the "second side" input code in its own loop.

Comment: To expand on what @ajb said, the `continue` keyword will repeat the whole loop, not just ask for the second variable again. So if you enter something other than a double for the second value, it will send you back to the start. You could put the second input question into its own loop or put it in a do/while loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `continue;` of your second statement makes your program to go back to the first line of while loop (next iteration).

To overcome it, you should put the second side scan statement in it's own `while` loop. Something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter Second Side: "); //move this inside below loop if you want to prompt user for each invalid input.

while(true) {
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        secondside = sc.nextDouble();
        break; //if we get double value, then break this loop;
    } else {
        sc.nextLine();
        continue; //you can remove this continue
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the changes you suggested but I am still getting the issue. My console output looks like this:

Comment: Please enter the two sides of a right triangle.
Enter First Side: 
g
Please enter a numeric value and try again.
Enter First Side: 
3
Enter Second Side: 
g
Please enter a numeric value and try again.
Enter Second Side: 
Please enter a numeric value and try again.
Enter Second Side: 
3
Hypotenuse = 4.242640687119285
Would you like to continue? Y/N?
y
Enter First Side: 
g
Please enter a numeric value and try again.
Enter First Side: 
Please enter a numeric value and try again.
Enter First Side:

Comment: @mrgopher that's seems a valid output. I can see that your program is recursively asking from `Enter Second Side` until valid input is provided. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: My issue is that it is stating the error message twice and the prompt for a side number twice for one invalid input.

Comment: @mrgopher can you please update your question and provide a sample response that you're expecting?

Comment: I updated the question with both the latest code as well as intended output for error checking

Comment: @mrgopher I see that you want to clear the console. If user enters wrong value multiple times then you want to delete the previous warning and replace it with new message. **That's a different issue.** You can google it as [How to clear console in Java](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?q=java+how+to+clear+console#safe=active&q=java+how+to+clear+console&*) and you'll get plenty of answers.

Comment: I was not getting it from a wrong value entered multiple times. A wrong value entered ONCE results in a duplicated error message and a duplicated prompt.